# Positioning image of navigationBar backButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimage, uinavigationbar

I add an image to my navigation controller back button like this:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ITButton.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
```

It works fine, therefore, my image is not aligned with the < back symbol. The image is a little above the symbol, I want both centered. I don't know why. I've tried to adjust this using:

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 0)];
```

but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to fix the issue, I was facing the same issue then I have Solved it this way

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if([self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] != self)
    {
        UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 26)];
        [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [backButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:TRUE];
        [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popViewControllerWithAnimation) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        UIBarButtonItem *barBackItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBackItem;

    }
}

-(void)popViewControllerWithAnimation
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: resize your image first, I am using 40*40, resize it upto your need

Comment: Thanks, but I'm just wondering if there's a way without instantiating a `UIButton` and adjusting it's frame, since iOS 7 let we customize the `backButton` of navigation bar.

Comment: bro as I said earlier there could be many ways, but I found this really cool.